# Stripe - How to use the Configuartion ID within a Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I created a custom payment configuration in my Stripe Dashboard
(https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/settings/payment_methods)
Stripe provides me a Configurations-ID starting with "pmc_"

My idea is that I can somewhere use this id as a property, but I found no way to do this within the SessionCreateParams.
The only thing I found was SessionCreateParams.PaymentMethodType that accepts an enum.

This solution would be also fine to me but unfortunately this enum is kinda limited.
I would like to offer Google Pay,Apple Pay and PayPal, but so far i could only select such payments on Strips dashboard but there is no enum for it...

This is my Service so far (I used a code snippet bcs code snippets always had formating problems)

```html
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StripeService implements StripeServiceInterface {
    private PaymentsRepository paymentsRepository;

    private static void init() {
        Stripe.apiKey = "censored";
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> createSession(StripeCheckoutDTO stripeCheckoutDTO) throws StripeException {
        init();

        SessionCreateParams params = SessionCreateParams.builder()
                .addPaymentMethodType(SessionCreateParams.PaymentMethodType.GIROPAY)
                .addPaymentMethodType(SessionCreateParams.PaymentMethodType.KLARNA)
                .addPaymentMethodType(SessionCreateParams.PaymentMethodType.CARD)
                .setMode(SessionCreateParams.Mode.PAYMENT)
                .setSuccessUrl("http://localhost:4200/payment-successful")
                .setCancelUrl("http://localhost:4200/payment-declined")
                .addLineItem(
                        SessionCreateParams.LineItem.builder()
                                .setQuantity(stripeCheckoutDTO.getQuantity())
                                .setPriceData(
                                        SessionCreateParams.LineItem.PriceData.builder()
                                                .setCurrency(stripeCheckoutDTO.getCurrency())
                                                .setUnitAmount(stripeCheckoutDTO.getAmount())
                                                .setProductData(
                                                        SessionCreateParams.LineItem.PriceData.ProductData.builder()
                                                                .setName(stripeCheckoutDTO.getName())
                                                                .build())
                                                .build())
                                .build())
                .build();

        Session session = Session.create(params);
        Map<String, String> responseData = new HashMap<>();

        responseData.put("id", session.getId());

        return responseData;
    }
}
```

I hope someone can tell me how to activate payments such as PayPal or how to use the Configuration-ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Stripe Java SDK added support for PaymentMethodConfiguration with [version 23.5.0](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2350---2023-09-14). I recommend making sure you're using this version (or later) of the SDK to be able to use the PaymentMethodConfiguration you've created in the Dashboard.

This snippet [in their docs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/multiple-payment-method-configs?dashboard-or-api=api#section-4) also shows how to use this with SessionCreateParams:

```
.setPaymentMethodConfiguration("pmc_234")
```